# In CMD / .bat I can change dir from C to D but not other way around?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cd

Ok so here is a copy-paste of my CMD window

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Developer>cd /d "D:\"
D:\>cd /c "C:\"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
D:\>
```

when I run cd /d "D:\" in C drive it works fine,
but when I run cd /c "C:\" in D drive then I get a error

So how do I change the Directory back to C drive ??

**EDIT:**

Here is simpler "copy-paste" of my CMD window

```
C:\>cd /d "D:\"
D:\>cd /c "C:\"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
D:\>
```

Doesn't make scene why its not working...

Comment: Don't you mean `cd \d "C:\"`? I think you just have a typo...

Comment: cd \d "C:\" doesn't work

Comment: `cd /d`, not `cd \d`.

Comment: How about `cd /d "C:\"` rather than `cd /`**c**` "c:\"`

Comment: its nothing to do withe "\" or "/" I just tried every possible combo of "\" and "/" same result

Comment: Thx Peter Wright your solution works

Comment: Yeah sorry, meant forward slash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cd /d "C:\"
```

is the answer

Credit go's to Peter Wright

Answer (score 16):

The parameter is always `/d` (for "drive"), so you need to do

```
D:\>cd /d C:\
```

instead of

```
D:\>cd /c C:\
```

Answer (score 12):

OK, I'll set it as an answer, then...

How about `cd /d "C:\"` rather than `cd /`**c**`"c:\"`

Comment: And you can also have a full path to a folder on that dir eg: cd /d C:\Temp

Answer (score 6):

You can change dir from c to d with simple command

```
C:\> d:
```

Then you will get

```
D:\>
```

Comment: Best solution bro, thnx

Answer (score 2):

To change `D:` drive to `C:` drive, type just `c:`:

```
d:\\>c:    
c:\\>
```

To change `c:` drive to `d:` drive, `d:`:

```
c:\\>d:    
d:\\>
```

Comment: he wants to change drive and folder *at the same time*

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `cd /x x:\` for your network drive, the command is always `cd /d`